# Electric potential at the bottom of a ring

Tags: homework-and-exercises

> A circular ring of radius $a$ has a total charge $Q$ uniformly distributed along the top half ($Q$ is distributed along the semicircle in quadrants I and II).
>
> What is the potential at a point located on the bottom of the ring (observation point is on the ring in quadrant III or IV)?
>
> The location of the observation point is described as being located at an angle $\phi$ measured from the positive $x$ axis. Find $V(a,\phi)$.
>
> [image]

Here's the work I have so far:

$$\displaystyle{V=k\frac{\mathrm{d}q}{r} \quad \lambda = \frac{\mathrm{d}q}{\mathrm{d}L} \to V=k\lambda \int \frac{\mathrm{d}L}{r}}$$

But I'm not sure what to put for $r$. Since its a semicircle of charge I thought of just $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$, but I don't think that's correct. Plus the answer needs to be in terms of $a$ and $\phi$. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should start from scratch.

$dV(\phi,\theta)=k\frac{dq}{r(\phi,\theta)}$, where $dV$ is potential created by small portion of upper ring that carries charge $dq$ and is sitting at angle $\theta$, and $r$ is distance between piece of ring where you need to know potential and small charge $dq$.

$dq$ then equals to $Q\frac{ad\theta}{\pi a}=Q\frac{d\theta}{\pi}$

Now you should be able to integrate using $dV$

$V(\phi)=\int_{0}^{\pi}dV=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{kQ}{\pi}\frac{d\theta}{r}$

From simple geometry we know that $r=2a sin(\frac{\theta+\phi}{2})$

To calculate definite integral, I suppose, you can change variable, using $\zeta=\frac{\theta+\phi}{2}$, which should collapse integral to something like $\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\frac{d\zeta}{sin(\zeta)}$